# How to convert List to JavaRDD

Tags: apache-spark

We know that in spark there is a method rdd.collect which converts RDD to a list.

```
List<String> f= rdd.collect();
String[] array = f.toArray(new String[f.size()]);
```

I am trying to do exactly opposite in my project. I have an ArrayList of String which I want to convert to JavaRDD. I am looking for this solution for quite some time but have not found the answer. Can anybody please help me out here?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You're looking for [`JavaSparkContext.parallelize(List)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#parallelize(java.util.List)) and similar. This is just like in the Scala API.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sean. Its converting list into JavaRDD.

Comment: Do you have any idea of "JdbcRDD" in spark? I am trying to implement it in Java but have not got any post or example about it. I have one link(https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/JdbcRDD.scala) about it. But I am not able to understand scala code for it.

Comment: @AmitabhRanjan need a separate question for that

Answer (score 6):

> Adding to Sean Owen and others solutions

**You can use `JavaSparkContext#parallelizePairs` for `List` of`Tuple`**

```
List<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
pairs.add(new Tuple2<>(0, 5));
pairs.add(new Tuple2<>(1, 3));

JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext();

JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> rdd = sc.parallelizePairs(pairs);
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to convert a collection to a RDD.

```
1) sc.Parallelize(collection)
2) sc.makeRDD(collection)
```

Both of the  method are identical, so we can use any of them

Comment: +1 -- This was the perfect solution for databricks. Though I don't think the sc eyword has meaning outside that context?

Comment: we get a sparkcontext object (sc) created in spark-shell, otherwise we have to create a sparkContext (There can be only one sparkContext per program)

Comment: oh, ok so its even more general than I thought. I have databricks goggles on

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a **.scala** file, or you don't want to or cannot use `JavaSparkContext`, then you could:

1. use [SparkContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html) instead of `JavaSparkContext`
2. convert your Java List to a Scala List
3. use SparkContext's *[parallelize](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#parallelize-scala.collection.Seq-int-scala.reflect.ClassTag-)* method

For example:

```
List<String> javaList = new ArrayList<>()
javaList.add("abc")
javaList.add("def")
sc.parallelize(javaList.asScala)
```

This will generate an RDD for you.

Answer (score -3):

```
List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("fieldx1", DataTypes.StringType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("fieldx2", DataTypes.StringType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("fieldx3", DataTypes.LongType, true));


List<Row> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add(RowFactory.create("","",""));
Dataset<Row> rawDataSet = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema).toDF();
```