# Create JavaRDD from List without SparkContext

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, apache-spark

I am writing some JUnit unit tests around a spark project.

One of the functions that I am attempting to test accepts a JavaRDD as a parameter, and I would like to create that JavaRDD programmatically, and converting from a List to the RDD seems like the most logical approach.

[How to convert List to JavaRDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952401/how-to-convert-list-to-javardd) suggests that I use [`JavaSparkContext.parallelize(List)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#parallelize(java.util.List)). However, seeing as I am doing this in a unit test, I do not want to instantiate a SparkContext object.

Comment: I don't think that you can to do it without walkaround, but you can use local spark for unit testing. This may help you: [http://blog.quantifind.com/posts/spark-unit-test/](http://blog.quantifind.com/posts/spark-unit-test/)

Comment: I am new to spark and want to access spark to aggregate cassandra data. Could you provide some getting started sample project for java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really an option, you need to use a Spark Context to create an RDD. One option would be to use [spark-testing-base](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base) (its also on [spark packages](http://spark-packages.org/package/holdenk/spark-testing-base)) (I am the author) to create a spark context for testing uses. If it would help I could extend it to provide an base class which provides a JavaSparkContext as well?

Comment: Thanks for that, if I had more than one test case that needed to be tested, I could definitely see myself going through and using this. But since I just needed it for a single test, I thought the overhead was overkill. Adding the base class which provides a JavaSparkContext would definitely be beneficial though!

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward solution is just to create a JavaSparkContext locally.

```
    JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext("local[4]", "test"); 
    //test code here
    context.stop();
```

This has drawbacks in that it will cause your test to fail in the event that the context cannot be created.